# Intermediate state of bottom sheet behavior in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I've implemented a BottomSheet in my application.
I want an intermediate state between collapsed and expanded, located in the middle of screen.

Behavior wanted :

- User slide up the bottom sheet. It expand to the middle of the screen.
- User slide up again the bottom sheet. It expand to the top of the screen.
- User slide down the bottom sheet. It collapse to the middle of the screen.
- User slide down again. It collapse to the bottom of the screen.

```
package com.example.test


import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.util.TypedValue
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<ConstraintLayout>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        val bottomSheet = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.bottomSheet)
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)

        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object :
            BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            }

            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                //Define a new peekHeight when user drag above middle of screen
                if (bottomSheetBehavior.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    if(slideOffset >= 0 && slideOffset <= 0.5f){
                        setPeekHeightBottom()
                    }
                    else{
                        setPeekHeightMiddleScreen()
                    }
                }

                //Settling
                if (bottomSheetBehavior.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING) {
                    //Bottom of bottom of screen > Force to collapse
                    if(slideOffset >= 0 && slideOffset <= 0.25f) {
                        bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
                    }
                    //Top of bottom of screen > Force to expand
                    else if(slideOffset > 0.25f && slideOffset <= 0.5f) {
                        bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                    }
                    //Bottom of top of screen > Force to co
                    else if(slideOffset > 0.5f && slideOffset <= 0.75f) {
                        bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
                    }
                    else if(slideOffset > 0.75f) {
                        bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    }

    private fun setPeekHeightBottom() {
        bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            32f,
            resources.displayMetrics
        ).toInt()
    }

    private fun setPeekHeightMiddleScreen() {
        val screenHeight = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
        bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = screenHeight / 2
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when i drag the sheet to the middle, my sheet is "shaking", i think the code is stuck in loop between the calcul of state "expand/collapse" in the middle of screen.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is enough

```
bottomSheetBehavior.isFitToContents = false
bottomSheetBehavior.halfExpandedRatio = 0.5f
```